# React Build - Failed to compile. ./src/scss/style.scss ParserError: Syntax Error at line: 1, column 39

Tags: css, reactjs, docker, sass

My react app build fails with the error that parsing style.scss fails.
[image: Build Log]

I am using Docker to build the image. The relevant Dockerfile snippet is:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine3.16 as builder
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY ./package.json /app/package.json
COPY . ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g
RUN npm run build
```

The style.scss is valid. The deployment worked a couple of months ago with the same style.scss. Anyway, this is the style.scss. I am using CoreUI react template, if that is helpful.

```
// If you want to override variables do it here
@import "variables";

$enable-ltr: true;
$enable-rtl: true;

// Import CoreUI styles
@import "@coreui/coreui/scss/coreui";

// Import Chart.js custom tooltips styles
@import "@coreui/chartjs/scss/coreui-chartjs";
@import "@coreui/coreui/scss/mixins/_ltr-rtl.scss";

@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

@import "rc-tree/assets/index.css";
```

Any idea or help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the full `node` image instead of alpine? Alpine versions are super slim and it may be missing a dependency you need to parse sass

Comment: Can't hurt to try! Will reply if it works or no!

Comment: Nope. Didn't work!

Comment: Try this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69032185/9090571